# Error:interface_registry.cc(203) blink::mojom::SensitiveInputVisibility

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, cefpython

Not sure of getting the error either the **cefpython** or **wxpython**. Below are the different versions used and Error log.

**Version using:-**

```
CEF Python 57.0
Python 2.7.12 64bit
wxPython 4.0.0a1 gtk2 (phoenix)
```

**Error:-**

```
[0405/131530.427048:ERROR:interface_registry.cc(203)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: blink::mojom::SensitiveInputVisibilityService requested by: content_renderer exposed by: content_browser via InterfaceProviderSpec "navigation:frame".

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please let me know the solution for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Related issue in CEF tracker:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2253/failed-to-locate-a-binder-for-interface

You would have to debug using GDB to get stack trace. See instructions here:

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/docs/Knowledge-Base.md#python-crashes-with-segmentation-fault---how-to-debug